# Scala looping over a java function

Tags: scala

I have the following Scala code in my program:

```
val parser = new PlainToTokenParser(...)
for {
  word: Word <- parser.next()
  if word == null
} {
  print(word)
}
```

where `PlainToTokenParser` is a java class in another library:

```
public class PlainToTokenParser implements Parser {

    public PlainToTokenParser(Parser p) {
        this.parser = p;
    }

    public Object next() {
       // some work here and return an output
    }
}
```

when compiling my scala code I get the following error:

```
... value filter is not a member of Object
[error]     for{ word: Word <- parser.next()
[error]
```

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `PlainToTokenParser` is not a scala iterator, you must create a scala iterator to use `for` loop.

```
val parser = new PlainToTokenParser(...)
for {
  word <- Iterator.continually(parser.next).takeWhile(_ != null) // Assume null is the end
} {
  print(word)
}
```

BTW: you can loop through java Array/Map because scala implicit create an iterator.

Answer (score 1):

The `for`-loop iterates over an object. You want to iterate over the `Word`s returned by `parser`. But your code actually takes the first `Word` and tries to iterate over that. (Also a problem is that `next` returns an `Object` while your variable is of type `Word`.)

Scala compiles a `for`-loop into a series of method calls. The [spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#for-comprehensions-and-for-loops) says it will translate into `map`, `withFilter`, `flatMap`, and `foreach`. The object you want to iterate over must have (at least some of) these methods for the `for`-loop to work. Looks like for some reason it's actually trying to call `filter` on the `Object` returned by `parser.next()`.

(See Zeng's answer for a solution. I thought an explanation would be useful too.)